# Redirecting input of an interactive script

Tags: bash, hex

I want to redirect input of an interactive program/script to a different program. I did with nc in the following way.
**Bash 1**
    nc -nlvp 100 | script
**Bash 2**
    nc 127.0.0.1 100

It works, but are there any better ways? Can I redirect input of an interactive script without nc/sockets?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the PID of the process you want to send characters to over stdin, then simply write to `/proc/$pid/fr/0`. Example:

Shell 1:

```
$ cat
```

Shell 2:

```
$ pidof cat
12345
$ cat > /proc/12345/fd/0
hello
```

Result in Shell 1:

```
hello
```